Why is there no option for wireless internet?
I installed Ubuntu on my Dell Latitude 5420 today. When setting up, it did not allow me to search for available wifi networks. The only option was to install without internet connection. Once I finished the installation process and set up, there is no option in the system menu for wifi, and network settings only shows wired internet. System menu
Network settings

Start with https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos to learn the information we need to diagnose the issue.
